# Add new LinearLayout on each iteration of Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-linearlayout

In one of my activities, I create a Linear Layout and some other Widgets when a bundle is received from an Intent. Currently, that Layout is overwrited each time I come back to that Activity. How can I create a new Layout each time without rewriting the code?

CODE:

```
public class FrontPageActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frontpage);


        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        try{

            String size = bundle.getString("size");
            int toppcount = bundle.getStringArrayList("toppings").toArray().length;




            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
            TextView t = new TextView(this);


            TextView tprice = new TextView(this);
            tprice.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);


            LinearLayout inner = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams innerparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            inner.setLayoutParams(innerparams);
            inner.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
            inner.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

            if(toppcount == 0){
                t.setText(size+" Cheese Pizza");
            }
            else{
                t.setText(size+" "+toppcount+" Topping Pizza");
            }



            tprice.setText(getPrice(size, toppcount)+"");



            tprice.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


            container.addView(inner);
            inner.addView(t);
            inner.addView(tprice);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){


        }
        final Intent sender = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), OrderPizzaActivity.class);


        Button badd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonaddpizza);



        badd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                startActivityForResult(sender, 0);

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Not clear, try to rewrite question.

Comment: Is that better? My problem is that if I access the activity and the try block of code more than one time it overwrites the linearlayout that I have created. I want it to create another one.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would need to create a data structure to hold the LinearLayouts, or provide a ViewGroup container for them to be added to each time.

Currently you are creating, modifying, and then overwriting the same `LinearLayout` in the `try{} catch(){}` block. Which I would guess to be the reason why it keeps overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you add new "options" to the "final order". Every time additional topping added you create a layout and fill it with specific data. And you want it to be aka OrderList. If what this app is about, you can have an application level variable myOrder:List. Add there toppings (topping = new Order()) and read list in FrontPageActivity.
Recommend you to have a separate layout for an order. Looping through orders fill layout with data and inflate in a container of Activity.

Idea in pseudo:

```
MyApplication extends Application {
    private static List<Order> mOrderList = null;

    public MyApplication(){
        mOrderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
    }

    public static List<Order> getOrderList(){
        return mOrderList();
    }

    public static void addOrder(Order order) {
        mOrderList.add(order);
    }
}
```

options activity:

```
MyApplication.add(order);
MyApplication.add(order);
```

FrontPageActivity

```
foreach(Order order : MyApplication.getOrderList()) {
   // fill layout with order data
   // inflate orderLayout into container
}
```